# Where did the zombie process go?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, systems-programming

```c
int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    printf("Parent: %d\n", getpid());

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        goto clean_up;
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        sleep(3);           
    } else {
        printf("Child Parent: %d\n", getppid());
        printf("Child: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Exiting...\n"); 
    }

    clean_up:
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to create zombie process on purpose (of course for experimenting/learning). After the child exits, the parent doesn't `wait()`s for the child. So, I'm expecting zombie to show up, in `ps -ef | grep zombie.o`. But for some reason it is not showing up. What could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the parent exits, all its children (alive or zombie) are assigned PID 1 as their new parent.  See [the `_exit(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit): " any children of the process are inherited by process 1".

PID 1 is normally the `init` daemon, and if it's working properly then it should  always `wait()` for its children.  So zombie children will be reaped immediately, and children that are still running will be reaped as soon as they exit.

If you want to create a long-lived zombie, the parent needs to remain alive but not calling `wait()`.